# Deploying Rails with Dokku - Dokku@Dokku.me Password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku

Im deploying a rails app to a digitalocean server with these steps.

```
http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/application-deployment/
```

problem is when i get to the Deploy App section it says

Now you can deploy the ruby-rails-sample app to your Dokku server. All you have to do is add a remote to name the app. Applications are created on-the-fly on the Dokku server.

```
git remote add dokku dokku@dokku.me:ruby-rails-sample
git push dokku master
```

When i enter that its asking to enter dokku:dokku.me password.

Does anyone know why or what is the default password for this? No mention of dokku.me before this step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't set a password on the user, so this is likely your ssh key's password.

Answer (score 1):

dokku.me is a placeholder for the documentation.  Replace it with your digital ocean droplet hostname

Answer (score 0):

I solved the mine by typing this command in my terminal

> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@serverIp "sudo sshcommand acl-add
> dokku laptop"

after type your password and you can try again to deploy